# HTTP Error 500 when running cloud scheduler to HTTP trigger cloud function to run pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/schedule-cloud-scheduler) tutorial about setting up a schedule to trigger your pipeline using a cloud function and scheduler. I've followed the tutorial up to the letter, to my knowledge. I made sure the pipeline runs without errors, and set up the cloud function. For setting up the job:

- I set the frequency to 0 9 * * 1
- Set the URL to `https://us-central1-[redacted].cloudfunctions.net/hello-world-scheduled-pipeline-function`
- For the **Body** section, following the guide I set

```css
{
   "pipeline_spec_uri": "gs://[redacted]/test/tab_classif_pipeline_test.json",
   "parameter_values": {
     "greet_name": "test"
   }
 }
```

Added OIDC token, set it to a service account that can invoke cloud functions (and other job scheduler permissions), and left all other fields to default.

After trying to run it manually, I get the following error, which I cannot for the life of me interpret:

```html
{
  "insertId": "j5h0k0flkeq6j",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "url": "https://us-central1-[redacted].cloudfunctions.net/hello-world-scheduled-pipeline-function",
    "jobName": "projects/[redacted]/locations/us-central1/jobs/hello-world-cloud-scheduler",
    "targetType": "HTTP",
    "status": "INTERNAL",
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
  },
  "httpRequest": {
    "status": 500
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_scheduler_job",
    "labels": {
      "job_id": "hello-world-cloud-scheduler",
      "project_id": "[redacted]",
      "location": "us-central1"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-04-13T15:09:04.120977064Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/[redacted]/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-04-13T15:09:04.120977064Z"
}
```

To my knowledge, I've been following this guide perfectly, so why isn't this working? Is there something wrong with how I set things up in the **Body** section? What could it be?

Comment: Does your service account have the proper permissions to Cloud Storage?

Comment: @JackWotherspoon I'll confirm. I used the default Compute service account, as recommended in the tutorial. It would be a bit misleading if the own they recommend we use doesn't have the proper permissions.

Comment: @JackWotherspoon I've just made a service account which had admin access to GCS, cloud functions, cloud scheduler, and general Owner access. It now says permission denied. What *exact* permissions do I need for this to work?

Comment: Who says permission denied? The job? The function? It stills not clear what's happening here. Cloud Scheduler shows 500 if the functions it is calling is failing. The logs of the functions show anything?